# Does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n}$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to show whether or not this sum $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n}$$

converges or not. First note that $$\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n}\leq\frac{(n-1)^n}{(4n)^n}$$

It follows that the sequences of partial sums $s_n$ and $s_m$ $$s_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n}\leq\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{(n-1)^n}{(4n)^n}=s_m$$

Since $(n-1)^n < (4n)^n$, we have that $\frac{(n-1)^n}{(4n)^n}<1$ when $n\geq 1$. The sequence $s_m$ is bounded from above by $1$, which means that $s_n$ is also bounded above by $1$. Because $s_n$ is an increasing sequence with an upper bound, we have that $s_n$ converges. Therefore the original series must also converge. What are the flaws in this proof?

Comment: Bad notations. You did not prove that $s_m$ is bounded by $1$. $\frac {(n-1)^{n}} {n^{n}}=(1-\frac 1 n)^{n}$ is bounded. Can you use this?

Comment: And how about root test?

Comment: How about $
\frac{{(n - 1)^n }}{{n^2 (4n)^n }} < \frac{{n^n }}{{n^2 (4n)^n }} = \frac{1}{{n^2 4^n }}
$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$ \frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n} < \frac{n^n}{n^2(4n)^n}  = \frac{1}{n^24^n} \le \frac{1}{4^n} .$$

Answer (score 2):

Just use the root test:

$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{\frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n}} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n-1}{(\sqrt[n]{n})^2 4n} = \frac{1}{4} < 1 \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)^n}{n^2(4n)^n} $ converges.